# Faster way to stream and parse XML than with xml-stream?

Tags: c#, json, node.js, xml, mongodb

I am trying to stream an XML file and process the data. The problem is: The file size is 70 gigabytes. I have a NodeJS application that runs [`xml-stream`](https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream) which streams the XML, takes 500-1000 records, processes them as JSON (output of xml-stream) and then dumps them into the MongoDB database. With about 9 million records, this process takes about 4-5 hours using xml-stream on my desktop PC with an i7 6700k overclocked, RAID 0 SSDs, and 32GB RAM. If I instead `cat` the file, pipe it into `grep` and grab all the trees (only 1 line), I can process the file in a few minutes.

cat and grep command:

```
cat motorregister.xml | grep "ns:KoeretoejIdent"
```

Here is my xml-stream code:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    XmlStream = require('xml-stream'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    url = 'mongodb://username:password@123.123.123.123:27017/database',
    amount = 0;

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'motorregister.xml'));
    var xml = new XmlStream(stream);

    var docs = [];

    // This is your event for the element matches
    xml.on('endElement: ns:Statistik', function(item) {
        docs.push(item);           // collect to array for insertMany
        amount++;

        if ( amount % 1000 === 0 ) { 
          xml.pause();             // pause the stream events
          db.collection('vehicles').insertMany(docs, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            docs = [];             // clear the array
            xml.resume();          // resume the stream events
          });
          console.log("Inserted", amount);
        }
    });

    // End stream handler - insert remaining and close connection
    xml.on("end",function() {
      if ( amount % 1000 !== 0 ) {
        db.collection('vehicles').insertMany(docs, function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          db.close();
        });
      } else {
        db.close();
      }
    });
});
```

Basically what it does: It streams the XML and parses the trees, then it converts them to JSON and that's it. I can do maybe around 500 per second, which is really slow, considering there are 9 million records.

Is there a faster way, using Java, C#, C, Python, etc., that can process large files like this? I don't care about the data being JSON. As long as I can create my own object with the parsed data, that should be good enough for me.

EDIT: I have now tried multiple different things, such as gzip and bzip, but they are much slower than simply `grep`ping the file. I do save the space, so I don't need to have a 70GB file laying around.

I'm still very lost, though.

Comment: Sound's like you are onto the the right approach with the `cat | grep` experiment. Should not be hard to find a package to filter the stream on "newline" splits and match the expression. So ideally, input stream piped to filter piped to xml event processor. We can build off worker processes but it would seems the biggest gain would come in the initial filtering. And I don't know what we can really do as an answer here aside from "google for you" in that regard.

Comment: @NeilLunn Hi again! I think the right approach could be `cat | grep`. Either using `grep` or maybe `awk`/`sed`, so we can do multiple lines. I'm not sure what I can do to pipe a whole tree (from start -> end) and process that. I can pipe a whole tree's XML using either awk or sed, but I don't know what to do with that data.

Comment: Are you sure the time is being spent on the XML parsing side and not the database update side? I don't know xml-stream (and can't suggest any alternative that will run on NodeJS) but I would normally expect streamed processing of XML to run at 1Gb/minute or better. The speed of the database updating process is going to depend heavily on the number of indexes to be maintained.

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes absolutely. If I comment out the `xml.pause()`, `xml.resume()`, and the whole part with database update and simply do `amount++`, it's still the exact same speed. Even if I create a `xml-stream` only application (no MongoDB or anything), it's just as fast. I can use any alternative you have, which I think I stated pretty clearly in my post. The XML streaming part can be done in any language, as long as it's faster.